# R - Need to subset a data frame using matches from a regex expression

Tags: regex, r

I'm looking to subset a data frame based on matches from a regular expression that scans a single column, and returns the data in all the rows where column 2 has a match from the regular expression.

Using R 3.01 and I'm a relative inexperienced R programmer.

My data frame looks like this:

```
data:

........Column 1 ..  Column2    Column 3
Row 1 ..data..........string....data
Row 2 ..data..........string....data
Row 3 ..data..........string....data
Row 4 ..data..........string....data
```

I'm using the following to scan column 2:

```
grep("word1", data$Column2, perl=TRUE)]
```

So far, I get all the strings returned from column2 that contain `word1`, but I'm looking to subset the entire row(s) where those matches are found.

Comment: please edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(data))` (where `data` is the name of your data.frame)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new.data.frame <- old.data.frame[grep("word1", data$Column2, perl=TRUE), ]
```