# Filter contents of data.table based on MULTIPLE regex matches

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to accomplish the same goal as is resolved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081613/r-need-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-matches-from-a-regex-expression), but I want to filter the table by *two* grep statements. When I try this:

```
DT[grep("word1", column) | grep("word2", column)]
```

I get this error:

```
Warning message:
In grep("word1", column) | grep("word2", column) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And when I try to combine this logic with an assigment `:=` in the `j` argument of the data.table, I get all kinds of weirdness. Basically, it's apparent that the `OR` operator `|` doesn't work with `grep`'s in the `i` argument of a data.table.

I came up with a messy workaround:

```
DT.a <- DT[grep("word1", column)]
DT.b <- DT[grep("word2", column)]
DT.all <- rbind(DT.a,DT.b)
```

but I'm hoping there's a better way to accomplish this goal. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe just use `grepl` instead of `grep`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the warning, but you should be able to do this with the single `grep` statement `DT[grep("word1|word2", column)]`. Or do the same with `grepl` as @nicola suggested.

Comment: @eipi10 Actually he is not getting an error, but a warning. Anyway, `grep` returns the indices, while `grepl` returns a logical vector (`grep` is kind of `which(grepl())`). So he is applying `|` to integer vectors (that may differ in length, since each word can appear a different number of times).

Comment: Thanks Nicola; I hadn't considered that. So either changing from `grep` to `grepl` in the OP code or going with a single `grep` or `grepl` statement (using `|` within a single regex) should work. (Also, I changed my comment to reflect warning rather than error.)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here turned out to be a combination of function choice and syntax in the placement of the OR operator `|`. `DT[grep("word1", column) | grep("word2", column)]` is confusing to data.table because each `grep()` returns vectors of indices (integers), which can be of different lengths depending on the data, and the data.table package isn't built to handle this sort of input. `grepl()` is a more appropriate function to use here because it returns a boolean of whether there is a regex match or not, and the OR operator `|` should be placed within the regex pattern string.

Solution:

```
DT[grepl("word1|word2", column)]
```